# How to manually clear the cache of my algolia index?

Tags: algolia, react-instantsearch

I'm using the algolia client directly in my node js backend so i don't use `instantsearch.js`.

I can easily querying/indexing/updating etc. my algolia index but i can't find a way to clear the cache because my app  always need to display an updated hits list in real time.

i've tried

```
client.initIndex('my index');
client.clearCache()
```

But without success. Always need to force unmount/remount manually my app to see the updated hits list.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Its an old question but since there are no responses ....

[Docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/advanced/cache-browser-only/javascript/?language=javascript)

Given the following instantiation:

```
const client = algoliasearch('H58KBL9VKQ', '••••••••••••••••••••');
const index = client.initIndex('your_index_name');
```

There are two methods.

`client.clearCache()` - when using multiple indices

`index.clearCache()` - when querying one index specifically

Note that BOTH return a `Promise` and both work only in the BROWSER, since the Node API doesn't cache results, there is no cache to clear.

Comment: Note the the clearCache() method is now async since V4: so you will have to change to client.clearCached().then(() => {...}); see https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/upgrade-guides/javascript/#the-clearcache-method

Comment: I just verified with Algolia API support. You cannot clear cache on just one specific index like that. That is incorrect.

Comment: Actually you could when the answer was written 2 years ago. But the API has changed substantially over the past year. No need for a downvote @jiminssy

Comment: Please consider editing and updating the answer to indicate that it no longer works.

Comment: Their support is wrong, or things have changed back, then. `client.clearCache()` definitely exists and works. https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript/search?q=clearcache It is a promise so be mindful of that.